# How to inject ObjectMapper int RouteBuilder

Tags: java, apache-camel

Right now I'm getting the objectMapper in processor as follows:

```
.process(exchange -> {
         var objectMapper = getContext().getRegistry()
                        .lookupByNameAndType("json-jackson", ObjectMapper.class);
      ...
```

I've tried to inject this object using `@BeanInject("json-jackson")`, but I guess I'm not using it right because it's null. I'm not using Spring or Guice, just plain old java and I'm initializing the route builder using `new`.

Also, I've tried to put the lookup in constructor of route builder, but I receive null there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dont use any IoC frameworks and create the class yourself via `new` then there is no dependency injection happening automatic. Then you need to lookup and set the object yourself. You can for example add getter/setter to it, and then create it via `new` and then lookup the object and call the setter afterwards.

If you have access to `CamelContext` then you can do the lookup as you do above, if not, you will need to lookup via the registry you are actually using, if that its JNDI or something else. Note Camel will by default use JNDI registry, but you can provide the registry to CamelContext when you create an instance of it.

Also if you have `CamelContext` you can use its injector to create a new instance which has some support for dependency injection (if you use Camel's annotations). There is a `getInjector` from `CamelContext` which should have APIs to create a new instance via the class type.